# I can't get YouTube Live Chat to display in iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I am trying to get my website to process my YouTube Stream and Live Chat together, but the stream works fine while the chat does not... I just get a link to the stream, "https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?is_popout=1&v=s2DZdjT0gtc", and then I put it into an iFrame, but it doesn't show up. I don't know why because if you go to the link, it brings you to the chat. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
/*Some Fonts Here:*/
@font-face { font-family: Rusty; src: url('BrushScriptStd.otf');}
* {
 font-family: Rusty;
 font-weight: Lighter;
}
.background
{
 background-image: url(0.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-color: f7f7f7;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:absolute;
}
.menubar {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.8vw;
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #3e3436;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  line-height: 0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0.7vw 5vh;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #2e2728;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #3e3436;
}
.Rusty 
{
 font-family: "Rusty";
 color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
 display: inline;
}
.content
{
 opacity: .85;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
 z-index: 0; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.menu > ul > .login 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 width: 100%;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
 position: relative;
 top:15%;
 width: 27vw;
 height:27vh;
}
.title
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 7vh;
 text-decoration: underline;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: inherit;
    text-decoration-color: inherit;
}
.feed-column
{
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
}
.border-right
{
 border-right: thick solid rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.text-center
{
 text-align: center;
}
.footer
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
 position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
 opacity: .55;
 margin: auto;
}
.yt-title
{
 font-size: 3.3vh;
}
.stream
{
 height: 45%;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.streamindicator
{
 border:none;
 width:100%
}
.column
{
 padding: 15px;
 float: left;
}
.margin-auto
{
 margin: auto;
 float: left;
}
.streamcontents
{
 frameborder: 0; 
 scrolling: "no";
 padding-left: 2.5%;
 padding-right: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-subscribe-widget-webp-vflj9zwo0.css"
    name="www-subscribe-widget" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>RG - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="menubar">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="aboutme.html">About Me 
            <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Gaming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Programming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">YouTube</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="current-item">
            <a href="#">
              <img style="width: 2.3vh; height: 1.6vw;" align="left" src="favicon.ico" />
              <p align="middle" class="rusty">RedstoneGaming</p>
              <img style="width: 2.3vh; height: 1.6vw;" align="right" src="favicon.ico" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="comment.html">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="login">
            <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="rusty title">ThatRedstoneGuy&#39;s Feed</h1>
      <!--<div class="stream">
        <iframe class="margin-auto streamcontents" width="50%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.twitch.tv/vikkstar123/embed"></iframe>
                <iframe class="streamcontents" width="50%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.twitch.tv/vikkstar123/chat?popout="></iframe>
      </div>-->
      <!--The stream code is here:-->
      <div class="stream">
      <iframe class="margin-auto streamcontents" width="50%" height="100%"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s2DZdjT0gtc"></iframe> 
       <!--The chat code is here:-->
      <iframe class="streamcontents" width="50%" height="100%"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?is_popout=1&amp;v=s2DZdjT0gtc"></iframe></div>
      <div class="border-right feed-column">
        <!--itemsleft-->
        <h1 class="rusty text-center yt-title">Colortone | Am I colorblind?! | W/Voiceless</h1>
        <div class="video-container">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-egJP-2ShRk?controls=2%20align="></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feed-column">
        <!--itemsright-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="border-right column">
        <div class="feed-column g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="ThatRedstoneGT" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <iframe class="feed-column streamindicator" src="http://streambadge.com/twitch/light/ThatRedstoneGT/"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Embedding YouTube live chat works but not on mobile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59349138/470749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube doesn't allow embedding the chat yet. [They're working on it.](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubegaming/comments/3rnuwf/embedding_chat_on_website/)