# Youtube live chat embed not working in mobile

Tags: api, iframe, youtube-api, embed

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=XX71LoT8AME&embed_domain=localhost" width="480"></iframe>
```

This is the Iframe code for the youtube live chat embed. 
It works fine in desktop view but return a javascript error in mobile view and no content is shown

Comment: Have you checked the following SO posts: [48244906](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244906/youtube-embed-live-chat-is-not-working-on-mobile-recently), [52468303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468303/how-to-embed-youtube-livestream-chat)?

Answer (score 3):

### Official YouTube [documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en)

> Embed Live chat
>
> **Note:** embedding live chat isn't available on mobile
>   web.
>
> During a live stream, you can embed live chat on your own site by
>   using an iframe.
>
> 1. Get the video ID for the live stream. You can get the video ID from
>      the watch page URL (youtube.com/watch?v=12345). In this case, the
>      video ID is ‘12345’. If you chose "Stream now," right-click on the
>      player and select Copy video URL to get the video URL.
> 2. Get the domain
>      URL for the site you want to embed chat on. If you're embedding chat
>      on www.example.com/youtube_chat, your embedding domain is
>      "www.example.com."
> 3. Combine the embedded URL in the following way:
>      https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=12345&embed_domain=www.example.com.
> 4. This is the URL for your iframe. Note the embed_domain must match the
>      the URL of the page you’re embedding the chat on. If they are
>      different, the embedded chat will not load.

Comment: Wonder why they removed this from their page.

Answer (score 2):

We just wanted to embed the youtube chat and found this on Google Support.

Unfortunately, Youtube chat embed isn’t available on mobile web according to google: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en

Take care,
I.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work on Chrome on android nor IOS but DOES work on Safari on IPad (IOS).